# case insenstive string replace that correctly works with ligatures like "ß" <=> "ss"

Tags: .net, encoding, localization, culture, cultureinfo

I have build a litte asp.net form that searches for something and displays the results. I want to highlight the search string within the search results. Example:

```
Query: "p"
Results: a<b>p</b>ple, banana, <b>p</b>lum
```

The code that I have goes like this:

```
public static string HighlightSubstring(string text, string substring)
{
 var index = text.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
 if(index == -1) return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
 string p0, p1, p2;
 text.SplitAt(index, index + substring.Length, out p0, out p1, out p2);
 return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(p0) + "<b>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(p1) + "</b>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(p2);
}
```

I mostly works but try it for example with `HighlightSubstring("ß", "ss")`. This crashes because in Germany **"ß" and "ss" are considered to be equal** by the `IndexOf` method, **but they have different length**!

Now that would be ok if there was a way to find out how long the match in "text" is. Remember that this length can be `!= substring.Length`.

So how do I find out the length of the match that `IndexOf` produces in the presence of ligatures and exotic language characters (ligatures in this case)?

Comment: Just wondering: Why only highlight the first "p" in "apple"?

Comment: You are right, I will modify this to highlight all matches ;-) thx.

Comment: Does `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not directly answer your question but perhaps will solve your actual problem.

Why not substitute instead?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string HighlightString(string text, string substring)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(substring)),
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text), @"<b>$&</b>");
}
```

But what of the culture?  If you specify a Regex as case-insensitive, it is culture-sensitive by default according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0sbec17.aspx.

Comment: I upvoted this, because it is a solution, but I will not use it because the performance of creating a fresh regex about 100 times per request will be too much for my purposes.

Comment: It is quite possible to solve the recompilation issue if you have to use the Regex multiple times per request (I take it there are multiple text strings to check?).  I can think of two ways.  First, you could use the static Regex.Replace method rather than creating the instance method as I do in the code.  Using the static method causes .NET to cache the regex (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f.aspx).  Or, create the regex outside the HighlightString method and reuse the regex for each Replace.  Finally, if the issue is multiple substrings, create a regex that combines them.